# How to compare dataframe dates with the values of row and column keeping weekdays and holidays apart

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, weekday

I have a dataframe that represents this:

[image]

I need to create another column `'Mark'` and here is why it is complicated.
For the value `'C'` execution day is `Sunday 8/11/2018`. The next day would be `Monday 9/11/2018`.
So I need to calculate the `weekdays` values of the `previous week`. For this case I need to calculate `1/11/2018`,`2/11/2018`,`3/11/2018`,`4/11/2018` and `5/11/2018`.

However, if the `next day` of `execution day` is `Friday` or `Saturday` I would need to take the values of the previous week `'Friday'` and `'Saturday'`. For example, `B` executes on `Thursday 12/11/2018'`. The day after is 'Friday'. So I need to calculate the average of the previous week's `Friday`and `Saturday` which are `6/11/2018` and `7/11/2018`

Initially I did not had the `Day` column, which I added afterwords by using

```
df['Execution']=pd.to_datetime(df['Execution'])
df['Day']=df['Execution'].dt.weekday_name
```

And I can get to the point where it prints something if `execution date` matches with one of the `column dates`. Here is the code-

```
for j,row in df.iterrows():
x=str(row['Execution'])
x=x[slicing]

for i, val in enumerate (df.columns.values):
    print(df.columns[i])

    if i<l1:
        val=str(val)
        val=val[slicing]
        if x==val: #Execution date matches column date
            print('yay')
```

I am trying to learn python on my own and I have started by learning `pandas dataframe`.
However, Now I am lost and could not figure out the logic to proceed. Can anyone enlighten me the way?

Comment: In SO you should not add SOLVED to the title of your question, what you should do is post an answer and mark it as correct. :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc posted the answer, but couldn't mark it as correct.

Comment: If you want to mark as correct your own answer you can do it in 2 days, those are the SO rules, :-)

Comment: I also recommend not only say: *this code works for me*, explains that part of the solution did the magic and why.

Comment: @eyllanesc done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for me with explanation:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
  for j, val in enumerate (range(0,l1-1)):   #l1 is the number of columns 
               #subtracted 1 to not take last column in account as I only need the dates

    if df.columns[j+1]==row['Execution']: #to match the date of column execution,with the column dates

        a=pd.to_datetime(df.columns[j+1+1])
        a=a.day_name() #to convert the date in to weekday name
#As for friday I would need previous week's friday and saturday values.
#Therefore, I subtracted 7 and 8 to get the required value. For all the other days I calculated carefully this way so that I get the days right.
        if (a=='Friday'): 
            mark=(df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-7)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-6)])/2
#df.iloc(row,column) was used to get the values right
            markList.append(mark)
        elif (a=='Saturday'):
            mark=(df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-7)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-8)])/2
            markList.append(mark)
        elif (a=='Sunday'):
            mark=(df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-7)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-6)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-5)]+MPDr.iloc[i,(j+1+1-4)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-3)])/5
            markList.append(mark)
        elif (a=='Monday'):
            mark=(df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-7)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-6)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-5)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-4)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-8)])/5
            markList.append(mark)
        elif (a=='Tuesday'):
            mark=(df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-7)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-6)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-5)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-8)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-9)])/5
            markList.append(mark)
        elif (a=='Wednesday'):
            mark=(df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-7)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-6)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-8)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-9)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-10)])/5
            markList.append(mark)  
        elif (a=='Thursday'):
            mark=(df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-7)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-8)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-9)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-10)]+df.iloc[i,(j+1+1-11)])/5
            markList.append(mark)

df['mark']=markList #To add at the end of the dataframe
```